# Unable to link existing workspace in Azure log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm not able to link my any of the existing log analytics workspaces to the log analytics service. Its showing "***It looks like you have no workspaces to link***".

[image]

Comment: do you mind providing more steps or screenshots? it would be helpful.

Comment: no permissions, perhaps?

Comment: What permissions should I give? My subscription is Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN

Answer (score 1):

Currently all workspaces are associated to subscriptions already and you shouldn’t be required to link it. The only function ‘Linked Existing’ radio performs now is in workspace recovery. When workspace is accidentally deleted and customer approaches Microsoft support to recover it. Once recovered by support, customer needs to select ‘Linked Existing’ and select the recovered workspace that shows up in that list and link it back to its original subscription. This is an intermediate solution which would be replaced by self-service recovery solution in future.